# How to send a file to the server using eclipse plugins?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I m doing a eclipse plugin project to create an IDE for a particular language.
To run the script,i need to send the script to the server and the server should run 
that script..
**The problem is i m not able to send the script to the server**(I have connected to the server and also done with the authentication process).I connected to the server using 
**"org.apache.commons.net.telnet.TelnetClient"** plugin..

Can anyone help me in doing this?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

The class can be used by first connecting to a server using the SocketClient connect method. Then an InputStream and OutputStream for sending and receiving data over the Telnet connection can be obtained by using the getInputStream() and getOutputStream() methods.

try dis link :

http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-net/commons-net/1.4.0/org/apache/commons/net/telnet/TelnetClient.java

Regards,
Neal

Answer (score 0):

Try using eclipse [Remote System Explorer](http://www.eclipse.org/tm/).

Here you can find a [post](http://www.venukb.com/2007/06/06/how-to-browse-remote-files-in-eclipse-ide/) about it.